# How to iterate through List of Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I have the following code :

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> allMonthsList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
while (getAllMonthsReader.Read()) {
    Dictionary<string, string> month = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    month.Add(getAllMonthsReader["year"].ToString(),
    getAllMonthsReader["month"].ToString());
    allMonthsList.Add(month);
}
getAllMonthsReader.Close();
```

Now I'm trying to loop through all of the months, like this :

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> allMonths in allMonthsList)
```

How do I access the key values? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> allMonths in allMonthsList)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in allMonths)
     {
         string year = kvp.Key;
         string month = kvp.Value;
     }
}
```

*BTW* year usually has more than one month. Looks like you need a lookup here, or `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` for storing all months of year.

*Explanation* generic dictionary [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) implements `IEnumerable` interface, which returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection. From msdn:

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.
>
> The foreach statement of the C# language requires the type of each element in the collection.
>   Since the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a collection of keys and values,
>   the element type is not the type of the key or the type of the value.
>   Instead, the element type is a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` of the key
>   type and the value type.

Comment: Where doe's `allMnths` come from?

Comment: Ya i know i need 1 month from it :) but this returns `Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
` when trying to use the string.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i think he ment you have a syntax error there.

Comment: @eric.itzhak have you added inner foreach?

Comment: ya i have. this returns this only for using `year` and not `month`, i tried `ToString()` it but didn't work.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona thanks, thats simple typo (I usually don't use Visual Studio for answers, thus can't see typos)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky nevermind i fixed the error, your code works thanks! BTW you should add a brief explination as to why.

Comment: @eric.itzhak hold on, explanations comes soon :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var months = allMonthsList.SelectMany(x => x.Keys);
```

You can then iterate through the `IEnumerable<string>` as you please which is a simple enumeration of all your keys.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to iterate directly through the `KeyValuePair`s, you can do `allMonthsList.SelectMany(x => x)`

Answer (score 1):

Your design is wrong. Using one pair in dictionary is meaningless. You don't need to use list of dictionary.

Try this:

```
class YearMonth
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
}

List<YearMonth> allMonths = List<YearMonth>();
while (getAllMonthsReader.Read())
{
     allMonths.Add(new List<YearMonth> {
                            Year = getAllMonthsReader["year"].ToString(),
                            Month = getAllMonthsReader["month"].ToString()
                                        });
}

getAllMonthsReader.Close();
```

Use as:

```
foreach (var yearMonth in allMonths)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Year is {0}, Month is {1}", yearMonth.Year, yearMonth.Month);
}
```

or, if you use .Net framework 4.0 or above, you can use Tuple

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> allMonths = List<Tuple<string, string>>();
while (getAllMonthsReader.Read())
{
     allMonths.Add(Tuple.Create( getAllMonthsReader["year"].ToString(),
                                 getAllMonthsReader["month"].ToString())
                  );
}
```

getAllMonthsReader.Close();

Then use:

```
foreach (var yearMonth in allMonths)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Year is {0}, Month is {1}", yearMonth.Item1, yearMonth.Item2);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily meaningless - what if the number of fields isn't known until runtime?  All your suggestions require that knowledge at compile time (which would work if the months list is just Jan-Dec simply, but not if it's a list of repeating months with other data that is read in from input).